# Extract Only Digits from Dollar Figures

Tags: python, regex

What I'm trying to do is extract only the digits from dollar figures.

**Format of Input**

```
...
$1,289,868
$62,000
$421
...
```

**Desired Output**

```
...
1289868
62000
421
...
```

The regular expression that I was using to extract only the digits and commas is:

`r'\d+(,\d+){0,}'`

which of course outputs...

```
...
1,289,868
62,000
421
...
```

What I'd like to do is convert the output to an integer (`int(...)`), but obviously this won't work with the commas. I'm sure I could figure this out on my own, but I'm running really short on time right now.

**I know I can simply use `r'\d+'`, but this obviously separates each chunk into separate matches...**

Comment: explanation for downvote please??

Comment: If this was in excel, I would just use substitute() twice - once for the $ and once for the commas...

Comment: @SolarMike not in excel

Comment: that is why I started the comment (not I hope you note an answer) with "if this was in excel..."

Comment: @SolarMike and that is why i had `Python` as a tag... lol

Comment: so looks like you have been given a good answer, but can't use it...

Comment: re.sub('[$,]','',s)

Comment: @sln interesting!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex for this.

```
int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "$1,000,000")))
```

works just fine.

If you did want to use regex for some reason:

```
int(''.join(re.findall(r"\d", "$1,000,000")))
```

Comment: what would the first method (`int(''.join...`) return if there were no numbers in the string??? i'm assuming without `int(...)` it would return an empty string. would it throw a value error if there were no numbers in the string??

Comment: @Anthony test it. Toss `int("")` in your REPL.

Comment: i did and it throws a valueerror, as i said in my last message. my question was would it return an empty string without `int(...)` if there were no numbers in the initial string?

Comment: @Anthony test it. Toss `''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "Some string that has no numbers in it"))` into your REPL. :)

Answer (score 6):

**You can't match discontinuous texts within one match operation.** You can't put a regex into `re.findall` against `1,345,456` to receive `1345456`. You will need to first match the strings you need, and then post-process them within code.

A regex you may use to extract the numbers themselves

```
re.findall(r'\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)', s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQ7IQ5/1).

Alternatively, you may use a bit more general regex to be used with `re.findall`:

```
r'\$(\d+(?:,\d+)*)'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQ7IQ5/2).

Note that `re.findall` will only return the captured part of the string (the  one matched with the `(...)` part in the regex).

**Details**

- `\$` - a dollar sign
- `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits (if `\d+` is used, 1 or more digits)
  - `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0 or more sequences of

    - `,` - a comma
    - `\d{3}` - 3 digits (or if `\d+` is used, 1 or more digits).

[Python code sample](https://ideone.com/C1O682) (with removing commas):

```
import re
s = """$1,289,868
$62,000
$421"""
result = [x.replace(",", "") for x in re.findall(r'\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)', s)]
print(result) # => ['1289868', '62000', '421']
```

Comment: i want to remove the commas... the only thing i want to match are the digits and i'd like it all in a single match instead of separated into chunks. is this possible?

Comment: @Anthony Since you want to match any amount of digit groupings, no. You have to either pre- or post-process the matches.

Comment: i basically want to turn `$1,000` into `1000`. there's no way to just select the digits as one group??

Comment: @Anthony See my code snippet. No, you can't match discontinuous texts within one match operation.

Comment: @Anthony Note that my solution will work for multiple values on a single line.

Comment: +1 for this: "You can't match discontinuous texts within one match operation. You will need to first match the strings you need, and then post-process them within code."

Answer (score 3):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """$1,289,868
$62,000
$421"""

print([int(i) for i in re.sub(r'[^0-9\s]', "", s).splitlines()])
```

**Output:**

```
[1289868, 62000, 421]
```

Comment: this seems to be what i'm looking for. give me a sec to test it quickly

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to extract the numbers with comma groupings, the easiest thing to do is just transform that into something `int` can handle:

```
for match in matches:
    i = int(match.replace(',', ''))
```

For example, if `match` is `'1,289,868'`, then `match.replace(',', '')` is `'1289868'`, and obviously `int(<that>)` is `1289868`.

Comment: will have to test b4 i give u +1, but might not have enough time to test right now

Comment: That looks so similar to the substitute() function in excel... :) plus 1

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regex for this. Just string operations should be enough

```
>>> string = '$1,289,868\n$62,000\n$421'
>>> [w.lstrip('$').replace(',', '') for w in string.splitlines()]
['1289868', '62000', '421']
```

Or alternatively, you can use `locale.atoi` to convert string of digits with commas to int

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')
>>> list(map(lambda x: locale.atoi(x.lstrip('$')), string.splitlines()))
[1289868, 62000, 421]
```

Comment: will have to test b4 i give u +1, but might not have enough time to test right now